# System-wide virus scans in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, anti-virus, clamav, ltsp

I installed ClamAV (`clamav-daemon` and `clamav-freshclam`) in order to set up a policy of regularly scanning my LTSP thin client setup for Windows viruses.

Currently, we have a variety of users, each with their own group. All files in their home directory are owned by each user, and to each user's group. How can I have `clamdscan` read *all* of their files, whether 0700 or not, while not running `clamdscan` as root? (which is just asking for problems)

Comment: There's a launchpad ticket open with your problem. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamav/+bug/450250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you should install a job to each user's crontab, so all files are scanned collectively by a user's instance of `clamdscan`?

Comment: We'd also have to disable a user's ability to edit their crontab, since a malicious user could just disable the scan.

Comment: Hm. So run a task as root (so crontast is not removable) and `su` to each user's  account just before launching `clamdscan` :)